# How to configure cloud9 to run a grails application?

Tags: grails, cloud9-ide

I installed `gvm` and `grails` on the C9 environment. Everything seems ok.

I run the app using this command :

```
grails -Dgrails.server.host=$IP -Dgrails.server.port.https=$PORT -Dapp.context=/ run-app -https
```

It looks like the server is launched, no error message.
But the app isn't accessible on the **app-username.c9.io** url

Has anyone managed to run a grails app on Cloud9 ?

Comment: Does it work if you do "curl localhost:8080" in your terminal?

Comment: @Tim no, I get the error :`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Comment: Seems grails isn't running properly. If you do "netstat -tulpn | grep 8080" does it show the grails process? If so then grails is working but not accepting connections for some reason, if not then grails isn't running on port 8080 or isn't running at all.

Comment: @Tim during the startup of grails I see
`tcp6    0   0 :::8080     :::*    LISTEN   1334/java`
But once it is loaded, as said in the console, there is nothing anymore. Why would the grails process stop ?